# Vuetify 3 bottom v-navigation-drawer with tabs and scrollable content not closing on swipe down

Tags: vuetify.js, v-navigation-drawer

I am using Vuetify 3 to create a bottom sheet for mobile using `v-navigation-drawer` with `location="bottom"` prop.

Everything works fine up to this point with swipe-down to close the bottom sheet. When I add `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` event listeners, all get triggered as expected.

But when I try to add a Tab component as per the [documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs/#fixed-tabs) with some overflow content, the bottom sheet overflow scrolls on swipe up and down and tab navigation works on swipe left and right. I believe this is because of `v-window` is inside the drawer. Here when I add the above event listeners, `touchstart` does not get triggered inside the bottom sheet.

I want to implement the swipe-down to close behaviour (following the finger position) to the bottom sheet tab navigation that has overflow content. The bottom sheet will open on toggle, scrolls up and down on swipe up and down, switches tabs on swipe left and right and closes on swipe down further.

But without `touchstart` event it is impossible for me to go forward with this feature. (I'm planning to get the swipe direction and build the logic when to pull down the bottom sheet)

What am I missing here? Is there any other way to implement this?

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/pasanjg/pen/zYLqKzj?editors=1010) to what I tried. (Toggle device emulation)

Answer (score 0):

add `touchless` to draver

```
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="app.drawer"
    touchless
    app
  >
```